# Combining Animations in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am animating a SVG "gear/cog" shape infinitely so that it spins endlessly, as follows:

```
gearAnim = Raphael.animation({ transform: rotation }, duration, 'linear');
which.animate(gearAnim.repeat("Infinity")); // rotate infinitely.
```

If I want to make the gear pulse (scale transformation) I do the following:

```
value.animate({
   2: { transform: "s1.2" },
   3: { transform: "s1"} 
}, 600, 'easeOut');
```

This works. However, the problem is that the scale transformation does not happen with the gear rotation. It stops animating, resets to rotation 0, scales, then jerks back into the previous animation.

Is there a a way of allowing the shape to scale once while also rotating infinitely? Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's the best way, but one option is to set the callback: http://jsfiddle.net/b9akz/106/

```
var paper = new Raphael('holder');
var box = paper.rect(100, 100, 30, 30).attr({ stroke: "darkgreen" });
var scale = 2;
var angle = 0;
var func = function(){
    scale = scale > 1.5 ? 1 : 2; 
    angle = angle + 120;
    box.animate(Raphael.animation({ transform: "s" + scale + " r" + angle }, 1000, 'linear', func), 1);
};
func();
```

There's some artifact in the beginning, though, -- it seems to only start scaling after the first rotation cycle is over.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. However, I don't need the shape to continuously scale. It needs to continuously rotate, and based on a user clicking a button, needs to scale once while still rotating.

Comment: You might be able to achieve that using SVG groups -- put the rotating cog inside a group and pulse the whole group on click. To my knowledge, however, Raphael doesn't support SVG groups because it would be hard to simulate in VML, so you might have to use a plugin (I seem to recall there was one) or handle the SVG directly.

Comment: I know, this thread is old, but you can use "..." to apply or prepend to the existing transformation properties in the newest version of raphael.js like this:
transform: "...t0,20"